# Flask-Mail password token reset not working

Tags: flask, flask-mail

The problem I am facing is that the token generated by the password reset does not work. The /reset code works fine, it generates an email with the following url http://127.0.0.1:5000/reset/InBpbG90cGxhbnQxODAxQGdtYWlsLmNvbSI.Y0Gq-A.SUlDTVz5SUYl0VpQQX2UJMzFfJs
( which should supposedly trigger the second code reset/. However instead of directing me to the PasswordForm it just return the error

```
itsdangerous.exc.BadTimeSignature: Signature b'SUlDTVz5SUYl0VpQQX2UJMzFfJs' does not match
```

The code used is below: it has two functions the first is to generate the token and send the email, and the second is what happens after the link is clicked.

```
@users.route('/reset', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset():
    form = EmailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first_or_404()

        subject = "Password reset requested"

        # Here we use the URLSafeTimedSerializer we created in `util` at the
        # beginning of the chapter
        token = ts.dumps(user.email, salt='recover-key')

        recover_url = url_for(
            'users.reset_with_token',
            token=token,
            _external=True)

        html = render_template(
            'email_password_reset_msg.html',
            recover_url=recover_url)


        send_email(user.email,'Password Reset Requested', html,user=user.email)

        return redirect(url_for('core.index'))
    return render_template('email_password_reset.html', form=form)


@users.route('/reset/<token>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reset_with_token(token):
    try:
        password_reset_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        email = password_reset_serializer.loads(token, salt='password-reset-salt', max_age=84600)
    except:
        flash('The password reset link is invalid or has expired.', 'error')
        print('The password reset link is invalid or has expired.', 'error','lol')
        return redirect(url_for('core.index'))

    form = PasswordForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
        except:
            flash('Invalid email address!', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

        user._password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your password has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('users.login'))

    return render_template('reset_with_token.html',token=token, form=form)
```

Comment: I found the problem but have not managed to resolve it, so in the reset_with_token function the token is being read as 'base.js' instead of 'InBpbG90cGxhbnQxODAxQGdtYWlsLmNvbSI.Y0Gq-A.SUlDTVz5SUYl0VpQQX2UJMzFfJs ' (the actual token itself), does anyone know why this is happening

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Did you find a solution to this? If you found a solution please share it.